# How do I format the url: for a jQuery ajax() request in CakePHP so it won't add a question mark to the url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm trying to call the 'tariff' action of my 'countries' controller using jQuery ajax() and pass it a country name in the following format:

```
/countries/tariff/countryname
```

However, with the following code ( set to GET ), it is calling this with the get `?` added:

```
/countries/tariff/?countryname
```

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#CountriesIndexForm select').change(function(){          
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            url: "/countries/tariff/",

            data: escape($(this).val()),

            success: function(html){

                $(this).parent().next('div').html(html);

            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

I understand its because the type is set to GET, but is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make url manually

```
url: "/countries/tariff/"+escape($(this).val())
```

Comment: I always make the urls manually. You know for sure how its going to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to append that to the **url** parameters and leave out **data**, i.e.:

```
url: "/countries/tariff/" + $(this).val(),
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the parameter directly in the url field instead of using data

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   $('#CountriesIndexForm select').change(function(){                          
      $.ajax({                
          type: "GET",                
             url: "/countries/tariff/" + escape($(this).val()),                
             success: function(html){                        
                  $(this).parent().next('div').html(html);                
             }        
      });    
    }); 
});
```